# Selenium Webdiver- Writing function inside a function

Tags: function, selenium-webdriver

I would like automate a drag and drop functionality. I have written a function for that. In that function there is two activites
1. Get the drag-from and drag-to element
2. Perform the drag and drop

can i write this as two sub functions inside ?

The following is the code:

```
public class dunelmtest {

 static WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    @Test
public void test() {


    DragandDrop();
}

public static void DragandDrop(){


                 driver.manage().window().maximize();                    
                 driver.get("http://marcojakob.github.io/dart-dnd/basic/");
                 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// Want a sub function for this             
          //Locate element which you wants to drag.
          WebElement dragElementFrom = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class='document']"));
          //Locate element where you wants to drop.
          WebElement dropElementTo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='trash']"));

// Want another sub function fir this         
          //Use Actions class and Its members of WebDriver API to perform drag and drop operation.
          Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
                Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(dragElementFrom)
                    .moveToElement(dropElementTo)
                    .release(dropElementTo)
                    .build();
                dragAndDrop.perform();        

}
}
```

So how can i create two sub function inside DragandDrop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your Question clearly but from what i can understand you want to do something more of a Fluent, the snippet below shows a Class structure that should help you achieve what you want.
Hope this helps

```
  Public class DragandDrop{

  public DragandDrop LocateElement(By locator){

  //Implementation


   return this;
   } 


  public DragandDrop DragElement(toElement){

   //Implementation

  return this;
   } 

}
```